# Creating a Lightning component that behaves just like a regular field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

(The feature that I'm working on is too confusing to explain the whole thing here, so I'm going to ask a simplified version of my question instead. I know that what I'm asking for sounds unnecessary, but please bear with me.)

Let's say I have a Lightning component on the Lead page that consists of a textbox. The textbox is named "LightningTextbox" and it looks and behaves exactly like a regular textbox field on the Lead object.

My goal: when the Lead record is saved, I want the value in LightningTextbox to be saved to a hidden field on Lead named HiddenTextbox. So basically, LightningTextbox is the interface through which users can insert data into HiddenTextbox. Is it possible to do this? Specifically, how do I make the value transfer over from the lightning field to the hidden field when the record is saved? I think it might not be possible to do this, but I just wanted to ask to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component with the textbox that, on submit, saves the text into a field on your Lead record. You can choose to save it to the hidden field directly, or save to another, visible, field, so that your user can see what was typed in later, and have a trigger on the Lead to copy the value to the hidden field.

For the component you might want to look at the `lightning:textarea`, `lightning:button`, and how to call Apex on the server side. The logic would be that the user types in the text, and then when the submit button is clicked, the component passes the value to the server (call Apex), so the record can be saved.

Searching for "how to handle a click on a button", and "how to get the value from a textarea component" might help you a lot with this.

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:button/example
2. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:textarea/example
3. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I see some issues with this solution. 
1. This solution would involve having multiple save buttons on the page (one for the lightning component and one for the rest of the page) which is not quite what I'm looking for.
2. Wouldn't these two save buttons interfere with each other? If the user clicks the lightning save then clicks the record save, wouldn't the record save overwrite the value in the hidden field to make it blank again? (Since it was blank when the page was first opened?) Also can you even update a record while it's being edited?

Comment: Let me get this. You want to have the component on the page, but you don't want a button, so it would "confuse the user" because there would be a button for the component and another for saving the record (the standard save button)? Well, the second one only shows up only if the record is on edit mode on the interface.

Comment: The "edit mode" on the Lightning interface is just the record form being open for the user to edit the fields he has access to. You can update the record on the background, but then if the user tries to update it right after, the platform would ask him to update the page (because he has the "old" version of that record on its page).

Comment: I start to think that your request simply isn't doable. You either have the custom component with your field together with the standard record form component, or you customize the whole thing. I don't see how you would implement the field alone in the component, without worrying about the record being updated.